# Clarification on database interaction within phonegap (uses W3C Web SQL)

Tags: cordova, web-sql

I have the following working set of functions which I have adapted from the phonegap api (http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#Database):

```
function onDeviceReady() {
         //Phonegap is ready. Open up the database and fill with data
        //
        var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
        db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);

}


    // Transaction success callback
    //
    function successCB() {
        //Database opened succesfully - now choose the database again
        var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
        //Execute an SQL transaction against it. The successful results of
        //this transaction will be in querySuccess function below
        db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
    }

    // Transaction error callback
    //
    function errorCB(err) {
        console.log("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
    }

    // Populate the database 
    //
    function populateDB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS PAGES');
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PAGES (id unique, data)');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO PAGES (id, data) VALUES (1, "First  page")');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO PAGES (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second  page")');
    }

    // Query the database
    //
    function queryDB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM PAGES', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
    }


    // Query the success callback
    //
    function querySuccess(tx, results) {
        var len = results.rows.length;
        alert("DEMO table: " + len + " rows found.");
        for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
            alert("Row = " + i + " ID = " + results.rows.item(i).id + " Data =  " + results.rows.item(i).data);
        }
    }
```

Looking at that. Am I right in saying that the database is created everytime the app would be loaded? That just doesn't make sense to me but perhaps this is the only way to do it? Unless I have coded it wrong

Comment: I don't think the database is recreated each time it's opened, judging from the behavior of the webkit StickyNotes demo app, which displays existing records when the database is opened, if it exists, of course. The OpenDatabase method of the API must create the database if it doesn't exist, and simply open it if it does. Though I don't know what happens if the size parameter is smaller or larger on subsequent open calls than it was the very first time. I would not re-open in the success handler. The code above does appear to populate multiple times.

Comment: If I do not reopen it in the success handler, it doesn't work at all :/ Hmmm..

Comment: `var db = null;` is needed outside onDeviceReady; then db = window.openDatabase.... inside the function.  Scope issue.

Comment: The `unique` column constraint would cause subsequent attempts to repopulate the (existing) tables to fail, but would not prevent the attempt per se. But the code is deleting (dropping) the table and recreating it. That is not necessary, and would prevent the database from persisting anything.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have modified the code and now it works without needing to re-open the database. Have also modified the code so it does not drop the database on each load (and tests show that it is now successfully pulling data back from db without creating it first).

Comment: So really now, I am guessing the best way forward would be to create a flag in a database table. So on first load it creates all the tables and inserts all the data. Then set the flag as true or on subsequent runs, it does not do all this again?

Comment: Or perhaps there is a way that I can check if table exists first?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` does that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than invoking your populate method directly below the open call, attach an event listener to the db's *load* event.

```
var db = null;

 function openDB() {db = ... };

.
.
.

 if (db != null)
         addEventListener('load', loaded, false);
```

and then populate the database with its initial data in the eventhandler for the db.load event.

Comment: I can't quite figure out your syntax. I have come up with the following but it doens't quite work: